# Get url of a website and convert html page of that link to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have created a form. Whenever someone pastes the url of a website such as https://google.com in that form and after hitting the submit button, it will convert the webpage to pdf and prompt us to save in the disk. Can anyone please tell me how to do this ? I know about DOMPDF

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: I am trying to paste the url of a site in a form and after hitting submit button, it should convert webpage of that url to pdf. Just like this one ---->   http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML2PDF library - [Html2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default)  - We have had good luck with that - however there are several caveats with using it -

- HTML must be correct
- Images must be full path (http:// ... )
- Not all style makes it through.